# Why did the value error keep coming in my tensorflow program?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

When I try to fit the model I built to classify images, I always get the error:

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer thumbnail is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: [160, 240, 3]
```

I cannot tell why this is, as the images are all in the correct shape: (240, 160, 3) per image. I put all the labels and examples into a tf.data.Dataset in the function loadData(). The Sequential model expects (examples, labels), so I guess this is fine.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import os
from PIL import Image
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

def loadData(nExamplesPerClass=1):
    path = os.path.dirname(__file__) + '\\croppedData\\'
    res = []
    labels = []

    for i, file in enumerate(os.listdir(path + 'pos')):
        if i == nExamplesPerClass:
            break 
        image = np.asarray(Image.open(path + 'pos\\' + file))
        res.append(image)

    for i, file in enumerate(os.listdir(path + 'neg')):
        if i == nExamplesPerClass:
            break
        image = np.asarray(Image.open(path + 'neg\\' + file))
        res.append(image)

    labels = [1 for _ in range(nExamplesPerClass)]
    labels += [0 for _ in range(nExamplesPerClass)]

    res, labels = shuffle_in_unison(np.array(res), np.array(labels))
    # res.shape = (200, 240, 160, 3) (examples, width, height, color channels)

    return tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((res, labels))

def shuffle_in_unison(a, b):
    n_elem = a.shape[0]
    indeces = np.random.permutation(n_elem)
    return a[indeces], b[indeces]

def main():
    model = tf.keras.Sequential(name="thumbnail")
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=48, kernel_size=(5,5), strides=(1,1), padding='same', name='1', activation='relu', data_format='channels_last', input_shape=(240, 160, 3)))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(5,5), strides=(1,1), padding='same', name='2',activation='relu'))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=(5,5), strides=(1,1), padding='same', name='3',activation='relu'))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='tanh', name='4'))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.4))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='sigmoid'))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation='softmax'))

    X = loadData(nExamplesPerClass=100)

    model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(), loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(), 
        metrics=['binary_accuracy', 'FalsePositives', 'FalseNegatives'])

    EPOCHS = 1

    print(model.fit(X, verbose=1))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to batch your dataset:

```py
X = loadData(nExamplesPerClass=100)
X = X.batch(32)  # or your number of samples per batch
```

The `fit` function doesn't have in-built functionality for splitting the dataset into batches.

Comment: Thank you! I just figured it out myself and I can confirm: It was the cause.